# Java Split a String with Regex expression

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I don't know much about regex. So can you please tell me how to split the below string to get the desired output?

```
String ruleString= "/Rule/Account/Attribute[N='accountCategory' and V>=1]"+
                " and /Rule/Account/Attribute[N='accountType' and V>=34]"+
                  " and /Rule/Account/Attribute[N='acctSegId' and V>=341]"+
                   " and /Rule/Account/Attribute[N='is1sa' and V>=1]"+
                    " and /Rule/Account/Attribute[N='isActivated' and V>=0]"+
                    " and /Rule/Account/Attribute[N='mogId' and V>=3]"+
                    " and /Rule/Account/Attribute[N='regulatoryId' and V>=4]"+
                    " and /Rule/Account/Attribute[N='vipCode' and V>=5]"+
                    " and /Rule/Subscriber/Attribute[N='agentId' and V='346']​";
```

Desired output:

```
a[0] = /Rule/Account/Attribute[N='accountCategory' and V>=1]

a[1] = /Rule/Account/Attribute[N='accountType' and V>=34]
.
.
.

a[n] = /Rule/Subscriber/Attribute[N='agentId' and V='346']
```

We can not simply split a string using `" and "` as we have two of those in the string (one is required and other one is not)

I want to split it something like this

```
String[] splitArray= ruleString.split("] and ");
```

But this won't work, as it will remove the end bracket `]` from each of the splits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your input according to the below regex.

```
String[] splitArray= ruleString.split("\\s+and\\s+(?=/)");
```

This splits the input according to the `and` which exits just before to the forward slash.

Comment: Hi.. Can you add another regex in this answer to split the string according to this pattern? --> ] and /

Comment: ok.. got it.. I think its this --> ruleString.split("(?<=\\])\\s*and\\s*(?=/)");

Answer (score 2):

You have to use look-behind here:

```
String[] splitArray= ruleString.split("(?<=\\])\\s*and\\s*");
```

Comment: Can you please explain whats happening in this regex? I don't know much about regex

Comment: [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)